# Moving Pictureboxes from left to right

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 4 pictureBoxes. I need they move until hit right side and then move to left side and again. But after 1st picturebox hit left side other move closer to him. How fix it ??
[link on video with problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PTPy3jCFI4nQp7j2M_ktowoWDx_AKuS1/view?usp=sharing)

```
    int changePositionX;
    bool change = true;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
        {
            if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag != null && x.Tag.ToString() == "enemy")
            {


                if (x.Location.X < 750 && change == true)
                {
                    changePositionX = x.Location.X + 50;
                    x.Location = new Point(changePositionX, x.Location.Y);                       
                }
                else
                {
                    change = false;
                }
                if(x.Location.X >= 100 && change == false)
                {
                    changePositionX = x.Location.X - 50;
                    x.Location = new Point(changePositionX, x.Location.Y);                                             
                }
                else
                {
                    change = true;
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this instead:

```
private int jumpDistance = 50;
private bool goingRight = true;
private List<PictureBox> PBs = new List<PictureBox>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (PictureBox pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
    {
        if (pb.Tag != null && pb.Tag.ToString() == "enemy")
        {
            PBs.Add(pb);
        }                    
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (goingRight)
    {
        if (PBs.Any(pb => pb.Location.X >= 750))
        {
            goingRight = !goingRight;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (PBs.Any(pb => pb.Location.X < 100))
        {
            goingRight = !goingRight; ;
        }
    }

    foreach (PictureBox pb in PBs)
    {
        if (goingRight)
        {
            pb.Location = new Point(pb.Location.X + jumpDistance, pb.Location.Y);
        }
        else // going left
        {
            pb.Location = new Point(pb.Location.X - jumpDistance, pb.Location.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my code doing its thing with four PictureBoxes:

[image]

Comment: This is has same problem

Comment: Can you show us a video of what you mean?

Comment: [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PTPy3jCFI4nQp7j2M_ktowoWDx_AKuS1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: See updated code. Hopefully that works better.

Comment: it's not doing anything now

Comment: @vopravil Are you trying to make it like Space Invaders does going side to side?

Comment: "it's not doing anything now" Then either you're not explaining your setup very well, or you're not implementing the code correctly...

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, I'm trying to make enemies like there

Comment: @Idle_Mind [lThere is image of your code implementing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GV_kNOhMlcMOKVYVKzfpqtWRX9i7nqdI/view?usp=sharing) I probably got something wrong

Comment: Did you wire up the `Load()` event of Form1 to the `Form1_Load()` method in the Designer?